# Spaced Price Listing with PHP

Tags: php, filter, price

I would like to list the periodic price with php. 
How can I do it?

For example: 100€ to 500€

```
Result:
100€ - 200€
200€ - 300€
300€ - 400€
400€ - 500€
```

This is my current code:

```
$start = 100; 
$end = 500;
$step = 50; 
foreach(range($start, $end, $step) as $i) {
    if ($start < $i) { 
        echo ' - '.$i.'<br>'; 
    }
    switch ($i) { 
        default : echo $i; 
    }
    if($end <= $i) {
         echo ' - Üstü';
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
100 - 150 
150 - 200 
200 - 250 
250 - 300 
300 - 350 
350 - 400 
400 - 450 
450 - 500 
500
```

How can I get rid of the last price?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: ...So you're simply asking how to replace `-` with `to`? Or do you want to only display the minimum and maximum values?

Comment: The currency symbol should precede the amount. E.g. €100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for loop should be enough

```
$min = 100;
$max = 500;
$step = 50;

for($i = $min;  $i < $max; $i += $step){

    echo $i.'€ - '.($i+$step).'€ <br>';

}
```

Comment: I should have spent more time answering and less time editing!